# Conditional probability in a replacement scenario

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose we have $x$ balls of color red and $y$ balls of color green. Now, we pick a ball at random and then replace the ball with $k+1$ balls of same color as picked (thereby total number of balls is $x+y+k$). In the second picking instance, we pick yet another ball at random, and it turns out to be green. Now, what is the probability that the first ball picked was red?

The problem seems to be a perfect candidate for elementary bayes theorem and inverse probability, but I am getting quite confused because of the replacement of the first picked ball. Like it seems that the picking of second ball is dependent on two things, $k$ and the color of the first picked ball. How do we proceed? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Presumably, $k$ is some fixed number.  Nothing in the problem statement suggests that $k$ is a variable here.  But, yes.  Your final answer should depend on the parameter $k$.

Comment: @lulu yes, $k$ is a fixed number

Comment: So, then just proceed in the usual way.  There are two paths which might lead to drawing Green at the end...either you started with a Green ball, did the replacement, and then drew another Green or you started with Red, did the replacement, and got a Green.  Compute the probability of each and apply Bayes in the usual way.  As a sanity check, note that, as $k$ becomes very large, the final urn will be filled with whichever color you drew first, hence the desired probability should go to $0$.

Comment: I would break the problem into two cases.  Case 1, with probability $~\dfrac{x}{x+y},~$ the first ball picked was red.  Case 2, with probability $~\dfrac{y}{x+y},~$ the first ball picked was green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advocate keeping things as simple as possible.  I avoid **complicated** Bayes Theorem analysis   whenever possible.  Here it is possible.

I will break the problem into two cases.  Case 1, with probability $~\dfrac{x}{x+y},~$ the first ball picked was red.  Case 2, with probability $~\dfrac{y}{x+y},~$ the first ball picked was green.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1}}$

The first ball picked was red. 
The probability of Case 1 occurring is $~\dfrac{x}{x+y}.$

So, at this point, there are $(x+k)$ red balls and $(y)$ green balls.  Now, you are given that the 2nd ball picked was green.  Within Case 1, the probability of this (now) happening is $\dfrac{y}{x+k+y}.$

So, the overall probability that Case 1 occurred (first ball picked was red) and then a green ball was the 2nd ball picked is

$$\frac{x}{x+y} \times \frac{y}{x+k+y}. \tag1 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2}}$

The first ball picked was green. 
The probability of Case 2 occurring is $~\dfrac{y}{x+y}.$

So, at this point, there are $(x)$ red balls and $(y+k)$ green balls.  Now, you are given that the 2nd ball picked was green.  Within Case 2, the probability of this (now) happening is $\dfrac{y+k}{x+k+y}.$

So, the overall probability that Case 2 occurred (first ball picked was green) and then a green ball was the 2nd ball picked is

$$\frac{y}{x+y} \times \frac{y+k}{x+k+y}. \tag2 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

Now that the *heavy lifting* has been done in Cases 1 and 2, it is less painful to apply Bayes Theorem.

Let $A$ denote the event that the first ball selected was red.

Let $B$ denote the event that the second ball selected was green.

Then, the problem requires you to compute

$$p(A|B) = \frac{p(A,B)}{p(B)}. \tag3 $$

In (3) above, the numerator represents the overall probability that Case 1 occurred.  In (3) above, the denominator represents the **combined** overall probabilities that either Case 1 or Case 2 occurred.

Therefore,

$$p(A|B) = \frac{\frac{x}{x+y} \times \frac{y}{x+k+y}}{\left[ ~\frac{x}{x+y} \times \frac{y}{x+k+y} ~\right] ~+~ \left[ ~\frac{y}{x+y} \times \frac{y+k}{x+k+y} ~\right]}$$

$$= \frac{xy}{(xy) + [y(y+k)]} = \frac{x}{x+y+k}.$$

Comment: Yes, the problem was straightforward. I had lost the practice so felt confused